# Linking columns and filling the column with data in MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

im trying to do something I thought would be very simple but im finding difficulty with it. I've only been trying to learn SQL for two days.

I have my tables here

```
+--------------------+
| tables_in_db       |
+--------------------+
| branch             |
| salesassistant     |
+--------------------+
```

my sales assistant table looks like this:

```
+-------------+------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------------+
| AssociateNo | BranchID   | Forename | Surname  | PhoneNumber | Email             |
+-------------+------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------------+
| 73127717    | 123456789  | John     | applesee | 786-996-666 | jaa1@cool.com     |
| 99889988    | 123456789  | william  | gate     | 244-807-853 | ego0@notcool.com  |
| 82721721    | 123456789  | stephe   | Works    | 770-378-763 | gas@1688.com      |
+-------------+------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------------+
```

and right now my branch table looks like this, but is empty:

```
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field        | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| BranchID     | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| AssociateNo  | varchar(8) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

how can I fill the branchID in the branch table with the ID I have set in the assistants table without having to type it in multiple times, and will this create foreign/primary key links so future updates will happen automatically?

thank you

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  You already have this information in the first table.  There is no reason to store it a second time.

Comment: both tables contain more information and there are more tables in the database, I've just shown a snippet. It's because the branch table will be the table linking products, suppliers, customers etc so it'll link together

Comment: IN that case use a trigger,https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: is there a simpler way? like an update column from one table to another kind of command? trigger seems like a bit of an overkill

Comment: You said you would like to populate ie insert so an update is inappropriate and you cannot insert to 2 tables. Trigger seems only way.

Comment: okay then, thank you